# Maximum term limit on js str.replace?

Tags: javascript, replace, str-replace

**Is there an upper limit to terms on str.replace**?

From brute force it seems to be 2,720, as it stops working at that line of data from my spreadsheet.

In the following simple web application for replacing an input from column A (a Chinese character) with an output from column B (a keyword for it). Is there a better way to make this web app? (perhaps in Python?)

https://pastebin.com/LE2qAXtL

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 
    $('#txtFirst').keyup(function(e) {
 
        var str = $(this).val();
       
        var res = str.replace(/ /g, "-").replace(/着/g, "-ING")
.replace(/耐/g, "-PROOF")
.replace(/咐/g, "-STRUCT")
.replace(/啦/g, "!!")
.replace(/了/g, "(-ED)")
.replace(/嘛/g, "(PAUSE MARKER)")
.replace(/们/g, "(PLURAL)")
.replace(/赵/g, "ZHAO")
.replace(/浙/g, "ZHEJIAN PROVINCE")
.replace(/郑/g, "ZHENG")
.replace(/呜/g, "ZOOM-ZOOM")
;
         
        $('#txtSecond').val(res);
 
    });
});
 
</script>
```

...

and so on.

Here is where it is hosted in a working version with only 2,720 terms. (I want to be able to include more data)

https://chkey.000webhostapp.com/